# How to change the CSS of a DataPager when we click a radio button option

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to change the color of a asp:datapager option through css by clicking on the radio button..

Where visited (only visited, not clicked on any radio button) pages will be of one color, non-visited pages will be of different color and the pages visited where the radio button is clicked will be of different color...

I want this to make a question palette in an online exam project in ASP.NET C#

Comment: paste some code what you tried

Comment: i am not getting any idea what to do actually...but i need this in order to make a question palette in an online exam system just like the bank exam systems...where visited question will turn red color...answered questions(after clicking the radio buttons to give answer) will turn green color...and a mark for review option...

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Cause then it's pretty easy.